# multiplication in multicycle datapath write from stratch

Tags: architecture, mips, processor, multiplication

I wanted to know how the processor does multiplication in a multi-cycle data-path right from the beginning i.e from Instruction Reading -> decoding the instruction-> reading register files etc.

In other word I wanted to know that given the booth's algorithm for multiplication implemented separately (a circuit is given) how will you extend the multi-cycle data-path to support multiply instruction using minimum resources.

Can you tell for division also?

Comment: Hi - I'm not sure if this is the best place for this question (although you do see similar ones from time to time) - perhaps ServerFault.com would be better for this question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another good link is the opensource OpenFire microprocessor core, variant/analog of MicroBlaze (which is based on DLX) here:

http://opencores.org/websvn,listing?repname=openfire_core&path=%2Fopenfire_core%2Ftrunk%2Fopenfire_top_syn%2Fhdl%2Fverilog%2F#path_openfire_core_trunk_openfire_top_syn_hdl_verilog_

Part of datapath for ALU and Multiplier unit is in `openfire_primitives.v` file.

Manual of DLX datapath with good explanation of pipeline *stalls* and *bubbles* is

http://www.cs.iastate.edu/~prabhu/Tutorial/PIPELINE/hazards.html

And there is info on mulitcycle ops (DLX)

http://www.cs.iastate.edu/~prabhu/Tutorial/PIPELINE/multicycle.html

So, operation which can stay in pipeline (need more ticks) will insert stalls (or bubble) to pipeline. You can think about this as stopping all stages of pipeline besides EX, which do a Long operation for several tisks.

Another Mul/Div unit of opensource Verilog is here: 
http://opencores.org/websvn,filedetails?repname=openrisc&path=%2Fopenrisc%2Ftrunk%2For1200%2Frtl%2Fverilog%2For1200_mult_mac.v

Answer (score 1):

For the simple cpu multiplication will be on the phase EX of CPU pipeline. So Fetch instruction, Decode it, Ask RegisterFile for input operands, Execute actual multiplication on ALU.

Depends on ALU variant, multiplication can take 1 CPU cycle or more (with storing of partial sums on each cpu cycle, then it will be on EX0, EX1, EX2 etc stages of CPU pipeline). Slow ALUs can be pipelined, so It will give result of first operation  in N ticks, and start different operations each M

The various hardware variants of multipliers you can get on the page
http://www.aoki.ecei.tohoku.ac.jp/arith/mg/algorithm.html